# need help in quiz using php

Tags: php, jquery

hello i am developing a quiz using php , the script load quiz from quiz file not from mysql. i want to show one question per page

with next question ability . and when a quiz is done show me the results button 
goals  :

1. one question per page
2. show me the result when quiz is done
3. thanks for any help :)

i tried many ways to make it work but with no good idea

```
 <?php
// This script displays the quiz selected

// Display the header

// concatenate the target path from the parent dir path


$quiz = $_GET['q'];
$this_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$parent_dir = realpath($this_dir . '../');
$target_path = $parent_dir . '/tests/';
$quizfile =$target_path+$quiz.'.qz';
if (file_exists($quizfile)){
include(htmlspecialchars($quizfile));
echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
}else{ 
die();
}
?>

<center>
<form action="quizresults.php?quiz=<? echo $quiz ?>" method=post>
<table border=0 width="100%">
<?

// Show all the questions and allow the user to select answers
for ($i=0; $i<$questions; $i+=1)
{
?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2 bgcolor="#999999"><font color="#000000"><? echo $question[$i]; ?></font></td>
    </tr>
<?
    for ($j=0; $j<$types; $j+=1)
    {
?>
        <tr>
            <td valign=top width=1><input type="radio" name="q_<? echo $i+1; ?>" value="<? echo $j+1; ?>">
            <td><? echo $answer[$i][$j]; ?></td>
        </td></tr>
<?
    }
}
?>
</TABLE>
<BR><BR>
<input type="submit" value="show results !"></center>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to be more specific as to what's wrong. Also, opening files like that is a serious security vulnerability.

Comment: For a start, you're going to get errors. You're missing `;` on the end of your PHP functions and `$question` variable is not defined

Comment: If you want to only have 1 question per page, you will need to define a page/question variable, and store the selected answers in a session

Comment: also, if you want to do this in php, why do you have jquery tagged?

Comment: you can use jquery to view one question and if user choose the answer, just hide prev question and show the next question.

Comment: i am using file_exist and die if not exist so there is not file inclusion @Shahar

Comment: it is defined in qz file as $question :) @AshleyBrown

Comment: can you write an explained answer plz @Jogjakal

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is with AJAX. Make a front facing page with your HTML. Start with question 1 and send answer to an ajax.php (name can be anything) using jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

In ajax.php process the answer to the original question and send back HTML for the second question and answer options as ajax response. Use jQuery's html method (http://api.jquery.com/html/) to integrate the html into your page dynamically.

Rinse and repeat. When done, return HTML with results. You can pass some parameters back and forth to keep track of what question you are on, answer totals, etc - depending on what you need.

Comment: with what specifically?

Comment: i can't apply your code to my source code can you provide me with it thanks